# for loop a tibble takes too much time

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, for-loop, if-statement

For the project I am working on, I am analyzing two datasets each of 500,000 rows. I had to filter these rows based on a value in one specific column. Here is the function I've coded to use on the tibbles:

```
theme_analyser <- function(tibble_to_analyse) {
 
for (i in 1:nrow(tibble_to_analyse)) {
  theme <- unlist(strsplit((tibble_to_analyse$themes[i]), ";"))
  if (any(theme %in% themes_to_use)){
    next}
  else {
    tibble_to_analyse <- tibble_to_analyse[-i,]
  }
}  
}
```

In this function, `themes_to_use` is a vector that contains a set of string values. The themes column takes more than one value, and each are separated by a ";". Therefore, I first split these values and unlist them.

The problem with this code is that it works too slow. It managed to complete the work for only 250k rows in 18 hours. What are the ways I can fasten this process so that it does not take as much time?

Assume I have a dataset like below :

```
A  B  
1  "bright" 
2  "shiny"
3  "bright"
```

I want to filter the rows so I only get the rows where `B` column is equal to "bright". My code was used to select rows where the `themes` column is equal to at least one of the values of the vector of values.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post some example input and expected output, r.e. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Without data it is hard to be certain, but it seems that `grepl` would let you identify the row numbers of the cases to include without a loop.

Comment: You're writing the entire `tibble_to_analyse` (less one row) every time the `else` condition is met.  Don't do that.  Instead, flag the rows you want to drop and after the loop completes, then drop the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach using dplyr/string from `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble_to_analyse %>% 
  filter(str_detect(themes, paste(themes_to_use, collapse = "|"))) # Edit, thank you @Jared_mamrot
```

Example data:

```
set.seed(123)
n = 10000
tibble_to_analyse = tibble(
  val1 = sample(c(LETTERS, themes_to_use), n, replace = TRUE),
  val2 = sample(c(LETTERS, themes_to_use), n, replace = TRUE),
  themes = paste(val1, val2, sep = ";"),
  values = 1:n
)
```

Plenty of speed improvement, but not as fast as @Jared_marot's base R solution.

[image]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think you need to use `tibble_to_analyse %>% filter(str_detect(themes, paste(themes_to_use, collapse = "|")))` to get the 'right' answer

Comment: thanks, Jon. Your solution solved the problem. Also, can you change your solution based on @jared_mamrot's comment? He is right.

Answer (score 1):

Without a minimal reproducible example it's difficult to say whether this solution is appropriate, but one of the reasons your loop is taking so long is that for each iteration of the loop you are writing the tibble and calculating `theme <- unlist(strsplit((tibble_to_analyse$themes[i]), ";"))`.

If you bypass those issues by vectorising the function it should be significantly faster - here is an example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(themes = sample(c("one;theme", "two;theme",
                               "three;theme", "four;theme"),
                             size = 10000, replace = TRUE),
              values = rnorm(10000))

themes_to_use <- c("one", "three")
                         
theme_analyser <- function(tibble_to_analyse) {
  
  for (i in 1:nrow(tibble_to_analyse)) {
    theme <- unlist(strsplit((tibble_to_analyse$themes[i]), ";"))
    if (any(theme %in% themes_to_use)){
      next}
    else {
      tibble_to_analyse <- tibble_to_analyse[-i,]
    }
  }  
}

vectorised_theme_analyser <- function(tibble_to_analyse) {
  tibble_to_analyse[which(gsub(";.*", "\\1", tibble_to_analyse$themes) %in% themes_to_use),]
}

res <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(vectorised_theme_analyser(df),
                                      theme_analyser(df))
autoplot(res)
#> Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Edit

With the simplified example data provided in your question, here is a simplified subset method and comparison with @Jon Spring's tidy_detect method:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(themes = sample(c("one", "two",
                               "three", "four"),
                             size = 500000, replace = TRUE),
              values = rnorm(500000))

themes_to_use <- c("one", "three")

subset_in <- function(tibble_to_analyse) {
  tibble_to_analyse[tibble_to_analyse$themes %in% themes_to_use,]
}

tidy_detect <- function(tibble_to_analyse) {
  tibble_to_analyse %>% filter(str_detect(themes, paste(themes_to_use, collapse = "|")))
}

res <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(subset_in(df),
                                      tidy_detect(df))
autoplot(res)
#> Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>